# Delete and Insert or Select and Update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization, enterprise-library

We have a status table. When the status changes we currently delete the old record and insert a new.

We are wondering if it would be faster to do a select to check if it exists followed by an insert or update.

Although similar to the following question, it is not the same, since we are changing individual records and the other question was doing a total table refresh.

[DELETE, INSERT vs UPDATE || INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624404/delete-insert-vs-update-insert)

Comment: I think more information might be helpful. How many columns? What is the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx) and perform `UPDATE`. If it was 0 rows affected - then perform `INSERT` after, nothing otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, this is the one we implemented

Comment: Update followed by insert can be broken if there are multiple connections attempting the same process at the same time - they both try the update, get 0 rows, then both attempt the insert and one breaks - if you don't have such concurrency concerns, then fine, but for a general case, it should be avoided.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Is `merge` atomic? I suppose it is not - so it is affected the same race condition.

Comment: @zerkms - merge is atomic - you can even use it to implement changes to a table that are not describable using separate update and insert statements (because of additional constraints on the table)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: oh, then it makes sense. Btw, I upvoted both merge answers right after they have been posted. Blamed myself that I forgot about it ;-)

Comment: The race condition can be avoided if the UPDATE and INSERT are placed inside the same transaction.The U

Answer (score 4):

Since you're talking SQL Server 2008, have you considered [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)? It's a single statement that allows you to do an update or insert:

```
create table T1 (
    ID int not null,
    Val1 varchar(10) not null
)
go
insert into T1 (ID,Val1)
select 1,'abc'
go
merge into T1
using (select 1 as ID,'def' as Val1) upd on T1.ID = upd.ID --<-- These identify the row you want to update/insert and the new value you want to set. They could be @parameters
when matched then update set Val1 = upd.Val1
when not matched then insert (ID,Val1) values (upd.ID,upd.Val1);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY`? First doing a select to check if a record exists and checking in your program the result of that creates a race condition. That might not be important in your case if there is only a single instance of the program however.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, email) VALUES ('Jo', 'jo@email.com')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE email = 'jo@email.com'
```

Comment: Only partly. If there is another process that queries the value it might not get any value at all if it queries just after your delete and before your insert.

Comment: `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does not perform any deletes.

Comment: @zerkms: I know, that was meant to be a reaction to the question part: "delete and insert" or "select and update", saying that "delete and insert" has a race condition.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion would mean always two instructions for each status change. The usual way is to do an UPDATE and then check if the operation changed any rows (Most databases have a variable like ROWCOUNT which should be greater than 0 if something changed). If it didn't, do an INSERT.

Search for UPSERT for find patterns for your specific DBMS

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the UPDATE method is the best. Instead of doing a SELECT first to check if a record already exists, you can first attempt an UPDATE but if no rows are affected (using @@ROWCOUNT) you can do an INSERT.

The reason for this is that sooner or later you might want to track status changes, and the best way to do this would be to keep an audit trail of all changes using a trigger on the status table.